# See all my posts across all Google Groups

Tags: google-groups

In the new user interface of Google Groups, how do I see all the posts to the various groups made by me?

Comment: You can still switch temporarily to the old group. I just added a comment, requesting the stats, because they ask you why you switch back

Comment: I am not sure if they changed it recently but my answer describes where to click to show your own posts: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/59368/25540

Comment: Don't know how a company like google forget about this basic functionality.

Answer (score 5):

You can access all your previous posts by viewing a post you have posted to previously.

1. Locate your previous post (any of them - search groups for your name/handle/user-name)
2. Next to your post, you will see "Post Reply" and a drop down arrow, click the drop down arrow and select "Show Activity"
3. And there you go, now bookmark it :)

*Only the most recent posts are shown, but you can click the posts over time links in the calendar listed below the recent posts.

**Also, switching the recent posts category drop down box will switch the calendar list shown at the bottom.

Comment: What a convoluted process, but it never occurred to me to search for my own name. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can see all the topics started by you and even the ones for what you have replied by going to filters and selecting the appropriate filter type.
[image: hope this helps..!]

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct option to get this information, By default you can see (Group->About Group);

```
Most Active Posters
This month
________________________________

Most Active Posters
All time
```

However you can search your name and you will get a count like `Results: about 15 for Aamir`.

Comment: thanks a ton man (y), Don't know how a company like google forget about this basic functionality.

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be a way to do this currently.

Answer (score 1):

On the left hand side of the page in the menu choices is a 'My discussions' section which does actually run a search (as you will see in the search box at the top) for:

> author:me

although the actual 'My discussions' does appear to have a slightly nicer UI it does seem to have the same results.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a filter you can set it to topics I replied to or topics I started.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Search using the term "author:me"

Comment: That only seems to work if you search within a particular group. When I "search all groups" I get nothing back.

Comment: But its still useful